# PyQgis open vector layer attribute table

Tags: pyqgis, table, qgsvectorlayer

Is there a `Qgs` dialog or widget that I can use in a standalone pyqgis application to open the attribute table of a `QgsVectorLayer`? this seems to be such a simple thing, there has to be an existing widget or dialog...

Update:
After some extensive search, there seem to be two ways to do this in pyqgis, neither worked well, I am just going to summarize them here:

Approach 1. use the `QgsDualView` class as below:

```
self.editor = QgsDualView(self)
self.editor.init(self.layer, self.map_control.canvas)
self.editor.setView(QgsDualView.AttributeEditor)
```

This will display attributes as below:

[image]

Approach 2. use the `QgsAttributeTableView`

```
lyr_cache = QgsVectorLayerCache(self.layer, 120, self)
tbl_model = QgsAttributeTableModel(lyr_cache, self)
tbl_model.loadAttributes()
tbl_model.loadLayer()
tbl_filter_model = QgsAttributeTableFilterModel(self.map_control.canvas, tbl_model, self)
self.editor = QgsAttributeTableView(self)
self.editor.setModel(tbl_filter_model)
```

This will display as below:

[image]

So, as you can see, both look very much half-baked. I did accept @Matthias Kuhn's reply as answer as it did answer my original question, but in light of the fact that it didn't actually work, I continue to hope that someone can give suggestions that could make either approach work better. I will certainly up-vote your answers and give confirmation, this will benefit the larger community.

Comment: Did you find a solution? I'm trying to display the attribute table too in a standalone application. I'm searching too and I will share my progress if it's successful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`QgsDualView`](https://qgis.org/api/classQgsDualView.html) which is the widget used inside the attribute table dialog in QGIS. The dialog itself (with all the tool buttons on top) is not in a library which is exposed to python.

Comment: yes, I was able to get it work inside a dialog and display the features, but it only displays feature id, none of the actual feature attributes are displayed. can you give an example on how to get all of the attributes to show up?

Comment: I guess you have to call `dualview.init( layer, canvas)`, did you do that?

Comment: yes I did. It only displayed feature id (the internal id).

Comment: Hmm... `dualview.setAttributeTableConfig(layer.attributeTableConfig()`, does that help?

Comment: `QgsVectorLayer` class has no `attributeTableConfig` method. `QgsDualView` class doesn't have `setAttributeTableConfig` method either. I think I know what you mean, I have to set the config to tell it how to display things, but I don't think the table config class is ported to Python yet.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is what you are looking for, but I can access the attributes like this:

```
# Assuming you have a QgsVectorLayer object called "layer"

# get a list of attributes
fnames = [f.name() for f in layer.fields()]

# print attribute "name" for each feature:
for feat in layer.getFeatures():
    print feat.attribute('name')

# print all attributes for each feature
for feat in layer.getFeatures():
    print feat.attributes()
```